# Implementing a function that takes in 2 collections of strings and compares them as if they are unordered in Rust

Tags: rust, vectors

I'm new to Rust and I would like to implement a function to compare 2 collections of strings. The function should compare them as if they are unordered.

In Python, I would implement something like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

def unordered_eq(a: Iterator[str], b: Iterator[str]):
    a = sorted(a)
    b = sorted(b)
    assert a == b
```

I then tried implementing something similar in Rust. I'm trying to collect both iterators into new `Vec<&str>` instances, then `sort()` each of those vectors, then finally do a simple `assert_eq!(a, b)`.

```rust
fn unordered_eq<'a, T, U>(a: T, b: U)
where
  T: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
  U: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
{
  let mut a: Vec<&str> = a.collect();
  let mut b: Vec<&str> = b.collect();
  a.sort();
  b.sort();
  assert_eq!(a, b);
}

// Example usage:
struct Item { path: String };

let items: Vec<Item> = ...;

unordered_eq(
  items.iter().map(|x| x.path.as_str()),
  ["hello", "hello2", "hello3", "hello4", "world"].iter().copied(),
)
```

Is this the correct / idiomatic way to implement this in Rust? How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make three suggestions.

1. Since the function asserts, name is `assert_unordered_eq`, right now its surprising given the name that it asserts rather than returns a boolean.
2. It's typical when taking an iterator as an argument to take `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator`. You call `into_iter()` on the `IntoIterator` to get an `Iterator` and then proceed as normal. The advantage is that your function can then take not only `Iterators` (which implement `IntoIterator` in a trivial manner) but also other items like `Vec` and slices.
3. Since your function is already generic over the lifetimes of the str, I'd take it a step further and making it generic over any type that supports `Ord` and `Debug`

Here's a sample implementation:

```
fn assert_unordered_eq<X: Ord + std::fmt::Debug, T, U>(a: T, b: U)
where
  T: IntoIterator<Item = X>,
  U: IntoIterator<Item = X>,
{
  let mut a: Vec<_> = a.into_iter().collect();
  let mut b: Vec<_> = b.into_iter().collect();
  a.sort();
  b.sort();
  assert_eq!(a, b);
}
```

Taking it a step further, for an assert function like this, I'd look at having it do some sort of diff between the two collections and tell me explicitly what's missing/added to make diagnosing test failures (where I assume you'd use this function) easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about duplicates, the idiomatic way would be to use a HashSet. This is faster in the cases where it matters and, in my opinion, cleaner:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn unordered_eq<'a, T, U>(a: T, b: U) -> bool
where
    T: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
    U: Iterator<Item = &'a str>,
{
    let a: HashSet<_> = a.collect();
    let b: HashSet<_> = b.collect();

    a == b
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(unordered_eq(
        ["hello", "hello2", "hello3", "hello4", "world"]
            .iter()
            .copied(),
        ["hello2", "hello", "hello3", "hello4", "world"]
            .iter()
            .copied(),
    ));
}
```

If you don't know if there can be duplicates, and you want to check for those too, you can either import `multiset` and use the `HashMultiSet`, or keep your current code. I tried making it better with `Iter.all()`, but it looks like the only true idiomatic way is to try to implement a multiset from scratch, which would be overkill.

---

As a bit of a side note: I'm not too sure about the type signature you have chosen (taking an iterator as an argument.) It seems a bit weird to me, and I'd intuitively make it take a slice, but I'll keep it in, as that was not a part of the question. :-)